# efficient way to loop through nodelist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, mapreduce

I often have to loop through elements in a webpage, get some attributes, and  send them to the server.
I have a list made up of user_id in each div:

```
<div class="user-box" user_id="1">
  //stuff
</div>
<div class="user-box" user_id="2">
  //stuff
</div>
<div class="user-box" user_id="3">
  //stuff
</div>
<div class="user-box" user_id="4">
  //stuff
</div>
```

Using jQuery:

```
let ids = "";
$(".user-box").each(function(){
 ids+= $(this).attr("user_id")+"|"
})
```

The ids variable looks like this "1|2|3|4|"

I tried using map/reduce like this:

```
    function doStuff(selector, attribute,separator) {
    let mySring = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(selector)).map(
            x => x.getAttribute(attribute)).reduce(
                (acc, cv) => acc + separator + cv);
    return myString
}

let x = doStuff(".user-box","user_id","|");
```

I get the same results.

How can I do this using javascript instead of jQuery?

Comment: reduce gets my vote: you are taking an array and producing a single value (in the end), at least in your example.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that your data model & view are mixed and so you have to extract the state from the DOM all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a different indentation, you can:

- use `join` instead of `reduce` to insert the separator. This will also avoid the addition of the separator at the very end.
- avoid the creation of one intermediate array: use the callback argument of `Array.from`

As follows:

```
function doStuff(selector, attribute, separator) {
    return Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(selector),
        x => x.getAttribute(attribute)
    ).join(separator);
}
```

Remark about `reduce`: you used it without initial value argument. Be aware that if you do that, and the array on which you call it is empty (no matches for the selector), you'll get an error.